# Accept an offer but have another 2nd-round interview scheduled

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, job-offer

I interviewed with two companies over the last month.
Mainly because of the timing, I got offer from the company A a week earlier. However, since the offered salary was a little under my expectations, I tried to negotiate for a higher salary.

Few days later, in the morning, company B schedule a 2nd on-site interview with now more senior management (COO and several VPs). I have accepted and schedule it for the specific day.
However, close to the end of business of the same day, company A called me back with a new offer satisfying my negotiated salary and gave me few days to get back to them with the final decision next week **(before scheduled 2nd interview with company B)**.

If I do accept the offer from company A...

- Should I anyways to go the 2nd interview and later reject the offer
  (unless it is significantly better -- meaning I would burn the bridge
  with company A if if I would accept by early next week before 2nd-interview with company B).
- Or should I write politely
  that I have accepted another offer and ask to cancel my scheduled
  interview.

Ignoring for now company A, which one will less likely burn any bridges with company B (some of my friends work there)? (assuming there is possibility of me going with company A).

The timing is also very tight. There is probably a little likelihood of me getting offer from company B before I have to submit final answer to company A.

Both positions are senior level, however, it is the first time I am making a major move. Not much of interview experience.

Comment: This question has contradiction. You initially said "gave me a few days to get back to them..." and in the first bullet you say you have accepted. Then you say "have to submit final answer to company A". Which is it?

Comment: Sorry for confusion! I meaning to say because of acceptance deadline, there is possibility of me accepting that offer before anything major can happen after 2nd interview with company B (unless they will give me offer on the same day, which I see unlikely). So I am trying to decide if I do end up deciding with company A. Show I cancel scheduled interview with company B.

Comment: Oh, I see that.  I thought it said "if I do accept" as the heading...meaning the "...since I already accepted." is the first conclusion of the acceptance statement...

Comment: I mean "if I would accept by early next week", before an actual interview date. Limited now by offer decision deadline. I corrected it in my question.

Comment: ok, so it's "before the interview"  In that case yea, you got to be honest one way or the other, but don't be scared to say you would like to compare the two companies before making a final decision and you need more time for that...

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Joe,

> should I write politely that I have accepted another offer and ask to cancel my scheduled interview." - this is the correct and professional thing to do. – Joe Strazzere

but if the second interview falls in the range of the waiting period, I'd personally want to just wait to respond until I know on the second one.

I have also told someone flat out that I had another job on the table and in process with and asked to extend the offer response period so I can give both companies a fair decision.  In my case they said sure, 1 more week in which case I was able to choose the one I wanted out of the two with both offers in hand.  This of course is up to the company, but it's honest and professional still.  I find if a company really wants you they also want you to want them and are willing to extend a little bit in order to make it come together without second thoughts and doubts.

Comment: If I give such reasons for extending an decision period, can company A came back to me with rejection of initial offer? or would the worst that can happen be just a "no" from them?

Comment: It's always a risk, I would tell them I am very interested in working with you, but want to show the other company the same respect as they haven't finished their decision process yet.  Then ask if they would mind waiting until x date for you to accept.  If you are sure to show your interest I don't see why they would suddenly withdraw the offer...if they did I would wonder if they really wanted you or is something else was up...Then on Company B you can tell them you already have an offer but wanted to see what they came back with.  It creates competition on who will get you as well.

Comment: If you honestly just want to work with the first company though just do as Joe suggested and cancel the interview.  In my position I actually wanted to work for the second company more, so it was in my favor as well...and I did work for the second company.  
Also, be sure to tell them you like the adjusted offer since they already adjusted it for you...always a risk though so if you don't want to risk it just do as Joe suggested and cancel the interview...

Answer (score 0):

If you did not accept officially you can talk to the other company. Even if you end up with company A it is always a good chance to get more experience with negotiations. But maybe you find company B offers something better (salary or work type).